# RxSwift - Custom class as observable

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm creating a custom generic TableView model to work with MVVM and RxSwift. I'm aware of the `RxTableViewSectionedReloadDataSource` class but not willing to use it now in my project.

The model is created and working

```
typealias TableViewModel = TableModel<CellDescriptor>

class TableModel<T> {

    var sections = [SectionModel<T>]()

    func add(item: SectionModel<T>) {
        sections.append(item)
    }

    // More funcs there...
}
```

I created an instance inside my ViewModel as such :

```
var tableViewModel = Variable<TableViewModel>(TableViewModel())
```

And then listen to event in my viewController

```
viewModel.tableViewModel.asObservable().subscribe({ [weak self] value in
    self?.tableView.reloadData()
}).addDisposableTo(dispose)
```

Several questions here (I'm fairly new to FRP)
 :

- How can I "emit" an event to trigger my subscription in the viewController from my custom class?
  I know that a solution would be to create my sections array as a RxSwift `Variable()` and then listen to it directly, but wonder if there's a way to make a class (or struct) itself Observable.
- Is there a better approach to this problem ? I went through the RxSwift playground and example project but it sounds like there's a thousand ways to do the same thing. Maybe an `Observable` is not what i would be looking for. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make the view model itself an `Observable`. It's unnecessary complexity and it's just not intuitive.  If you really wanted to, then take a look at how `Variable` is implemented, which should give you an idea of how to do it.

Instead, just use a subject (such as `Variable`) to hold onto your data within your view model.